# Postgresql querying double nested json

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing, database-performance, jsonb

I am using postgres 9.4. I have a JSON type column called "data" in "list" table and the data stored in it is in the format

```
{
    "pages":[
         {
             "pageName" : "test",
             "components" : [
                  {
                      "name" : "comp1",
                      "type" : "text",
                      "value" : "val1"
                  },
                  {
                      "name" : "comp2",
                      "type" : "grade",
                      "value" : 7
                  }
             ]
         }
    ]
}
```

I need to query all component values for all lists that have component of type "grade".
I currently use this query:

```
select avg((comp->>'value')::int)
from list,
  jsonb_array_elements(data->'pages') as page ,
  jsonb_array_elements(page->'components') as comp
where comp @> '{"type":"grade"}' and (comp->>'value') IS NOT NULL;
```

The problem is i think this is a very inefficient, and as far as i can see from explain, it does not use any index which i set on the data column as using GIN(data jsonb_path_ops);

Is there a more efficient way to query double nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html):

> The default GIN operator class for `jsonb` supports queries with the `@>`, `?`, `?&` and `?|` operators.

So, uses of `jsonb_array_elements` won't use any index (cannot use anyway since it's a set-returning function).

What you *can* do is to pre-filter your rows from the table with `data @> '{"pages":[{"components":[{"type": "grade"}]}]}'` (BTW: `data` is a keyword, please don't use it as a column name).

But you still need the `comp @> '{"type":"grade"}'` filter to exclude any non-grade typed object within the same row, which contains at least one grade typed object.

Also, you don't need `(comp->>'value') IS NOT NULL`: `avg()` won't count `NULL`s in its result. But, you may need a type-check `jsonb_typeof(comp->'value') = 'number'`, because the number-cast may throw an exception when `comp->>'value'` does not represent a number (and the appropriate type for JSON's number is `numeric` -- or `decimal` -- in PostgreSQL)

```
with list(data) as (
  values (jsonb '{"pages":[{},{"pageName":"test","components":[{},{"name":"comp1","type":"text","value":"val1"},{"name":"comp2","type":"grade","value":7}]}]}'),
         (jsonb '{"pages":[{"pageName":"test","components":[{"name":"comp3","type":"text","value":"val3"},{"name":"comp4","type":"not-grade","value":9}]}]}')
)
select avg((comp->>'value')::numeric)
from   list,
       jsonb_array_elements(data->'pages') as page,
       jsonb_array_elements(page->'components') as comp
where  data @> '{"pages":[{"components":[{"type": "grade"}]}]}'
and    comp @> '{"type":"grade"}' and jsonb_typeof(comp->'value') = 'number';
```